# Complete measure spaces: Understanding a part of a proof.

Tags: measure-theory

I don't understand the part that I underlined with green, I don't see why such an $N$ must exist. Can you explain it to me? Thanks..

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with abstract measure theory but I wonder if in the completion of $M$ the only measure zero sets are the subsets of sets in $M$ which have $M$-measure zero?  If this is true then it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the completion the measure of $A$ is defined as the inf over $M$-measurable sets containing $A$.  So if $A$ has measure $0$ in the completion, we can choose a countable sequence of $M$-measureable sets decreasing in $M$-measure to $0$.  Taking the intersection of them, which is $M$-measureable, we have a set with $M$-measure $0$ which contains $A$.

In your problem, the union of the $E_i$ has measure $0$ in the completion, so applying the above we get the set $N$ of $M$-measure zero.

EDIT: using the definition provided by Twink write $E_i = E_i'\cup F_i$ where $F_i\subset F_i'$ and $E_i'$ and $F_i'$ are $M$-measure zero.  Then the union over all $E_i'$ and $F_i'$ is $M$-measure zero and contains the union of the $E_i$.

Comment: Hmm.. I have another definition of completion of a measure space, it's $\overline{\mathcal{M}}=\{E \cup F : E\in \mathcal{M} \text{ and } F \subseteq N, \text{ where } \mu(N)=0\}$.

Comment: But what is the definition of the actual measure on the completion?

Comment: $\overline{\mu}(E \cup F)=\mu(E)$.

Comment: Ok then each $E_i$ is of that form so it is a union of a set of measure zero with a subset of another set of measure zero.  So the union of $E_i$ is contained a union of sets of measure zero.